# Hide/Disable some feature RTeditor Android?

Tags: android

I have question about [RTEditor](https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor) library for Android. I want to hide / disable some features, i.e: "Insert Image" & "Camera" button on toolbar?

Does anybody know how to hide these buttons?

I already read the manual guide on site but didn't found any clue on how to hide / custom toolbar.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it manually in code, ie:

```
View insertImageBtn = findViewById(R.id.action_insert_image);
insertImageBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```